# Form alignment acting weird

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment

I am trying to have my forms float right, so that it looks neat when everything is placed next to each other, and it works fine, EXCEPT for the first 2? That is what weirds me out? It works great after the first 2. Here is a screenshot that says it all and my HTML code

```
    <head>
 <title>New user</title>
 <style type="text/css">
    #form_container {
        width: 25%;
    }

    #form_container input {
        float: right;
        clear: both;
    }
 </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="form_container">
        <form action="" method="post">
            Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
            Password: <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
            Password again: <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
            Password triple: <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

[image: Screenshot example]

Why is there that "space" between the first and second ones?

Thanks on advance everyone!

Comment: Try using a `label` tag to wrap around the input and text. Like so, `<label for="username">Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" /></label>`

Comment: Just tried, didn't solve it :( same issue

Comment: Refer to Sean's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply because you are asking for a password 3 times.. the markup doesn't like that and throws a random gap at you.

In all seriousness, there are a few ways to fix this.. the easiest is to set `clear:both` on the `br`.. that was causing the gap.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8vL3h/)

```
br {
    clear:both;
}
```

Also, remove `clear:both` from `#form_container input` as that isn't needed anymore.

```
#form_container input {
    float: right;
}
```

I'd also suggest adding a `label` to each input for validation purposes.

Comment: Haha, that made me laugh! I was just like, is that for real? when i read the first 2 lines ^^

That fixed it champ, and i will accept ur answer when it allows me in 3 minutes :) thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your markup a bit to add labels (which you could have anyway), and you can ditch the `<br>`'s completely. Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/designingsean/rWfek/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="form_container">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
        <label>Password again</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
        <label>Password triple</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
    </form>
</div>
```

The important bit of CSS:

```
label {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is fine, but I also suggest wrapping everything in `label`.

The advantage is that when you click on the label text, 'Username: ', it will automatically put focus in the input box.  While this might seem small, it really helps on touch devices, and especially on radio inputs -- try tapping the little 10x10 radio box.  Much nicer and more intuitive with `label`.

```
<label>Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" /></label>
```

and in the CSS:

```
#form_container label {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

Also, if you didn't already know this, I suggest using `<input type="password"/>` for passwords.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/Z8gXN/).